# Problem with event unsubscribing OnDisable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events

I register events in OnEnable and unregister them in OnDisable. In most cases it works but I have one simple script which is causing the `MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GraphicsSwitch' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.` when I load a new scene and invoke the event by pressing a button.

I know that the OnDisable is called as I checked with Debug.Log. The event is not invoked in the new scene before I press a button in the new scene.

After adding `if (this != null)` the error is gone. Checking if the gameObject is null is not working. It seems that the event is not unsubscribed and the method is called on destroyed object from the previous scene.

The code is very simple:

```
private void OnEnable()
{
    AdjustGraphics();
    GameSettings.GraphicsChanged += AdjustGraphics;
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    GameSettings.GraphicsChanged -= AdjustGraphics;
}

private void AdjustGraphics()
{
    //without this line I get the error
    if (this != null)
        gameObject.SetActive(GameSettings.Graphics >= requiredQuality);
}
```

Method AdjustGraphics should not be called in the new loaded scene. I thought the objects should be unsubscribed without any delay. **Is it something I am missing when it comes to unsubscribing events?**

I know objects in Unity are not destroyed right away but the **OnDisable is called on time so my script/object should not listen to GameSettings.GraphicsChanged event anymore when new scene is loaded.**

Comment: It suggests that somehow it has subscribed more than once.

Comment: You could try with if(GameSettings != null) GameSettings.GraphicsChanged -= AdjustGraphics;

Comment: before doing `+=` you should always also do a `-=`. This is allowed even if the callback wasn't added before and makes sure it is always only added exactly once.

Comment: Thank you to all and @derHugo thank you for a good tip. Didn't know this is allowed.

Comment: I still get the Exception with `-=` before `+=`. I checked all references and this code is the only place where I subscribe or unsubscribe. I have another script which has the same method name but this should't be the issue?

Comment: you could put a breakpoint to the line and run it so you can inspect the state of the variables.

Comment: @Everts the exception has to be coming from the component itself (`this`) or `gameObject`. For the static class `GameSettimgs` there will never be a `MissingReferenceException` since it exists "always". Also `GameSettings.Graphics` doesn't seem to be a `MonoBehaviour`. A `MissingReferenceException` rather is a hint that it was a once existing `Object` (= `Component`, `GameObject` or `ScriptableObject`) that was destroyed. Basically the error log already tells exactly what the issue is.

Comment: @Dave could you just to be sure go to visual Studio, click on the `GraphicsChanged` hit F12 and go to `Usages`. For debugging you could also add a `List<GraphicSwitch>` and add and remove the component accordingly everytime you subscribe or unsubscribe. Additionally you could debug with breakpoints in `OnEnable` and `OnDisable` and check if they are really called equal amount of times. Maybe something unwanted survives somewhere

Answer (score 0):

This link helped me:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-remove-and-inputaction-phase-callback.894601/

```
private void doSomething(CallbackContext ctx)
{
// do the thing
}

//register
action.started += doSomething;
//unregsiter
action.started -= doSomething;
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31796223)

Answer (score -1):

Correct me if I'm wrong but when you loading a new scene, your objects are destroyed hence the `MissingReferenceException` unless you use [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html).

If you don't want to use it, then make sure to initialize the object at the start of the scene load i.e. make sure your object exists in the scene before calling any of its functions.

Comment: Objects are destroyed when new scene loads and that is why you need to unsubscribe. This is not what I am asking. Not a downvote from me ;)